# Getting twitter screename in oauth

Tags: symfony, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am making an application with [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle).

In this class, I can retrieve twitter ID and access token, but I am not sure how to get the screen name:

```
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName(); // I can get service name
        $username = $response->getUsername();//I can get username
        $accesstoken = $response->getAccessToken(); //I can get access token
        $screen_name = $response->getScreenName(); // error,how can I get screen name?????
```

How can I get twitter screen name?

Comment: Assuming there is such a function, I guess it should be `getScreenName`. You are missing an _n_.

Comment: Thanks @kapep, I have tried getScreenName and getScreenname ,but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem already, but here's the solution: You can access the screen name by  checking your `vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner`, and then looking for your resource owner file. You can see an array at the beginning of the class named `$paths`. All you have to do is use the key to access the wanted value.

For twitter, you can see this:

```
    protected $paths = array(
    'identifier' => 'id_str',
    'nickname'   => 'screen_name',
    'realname'   => 'name',
);
```

All you have to do is use

```
$response->getNickName();
```

So, let's say you want to save your user name, you'll write something like this :

```
$user->setUsername($response->getNickName());
```

And Voila!